# When can you dynamically add a field to an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I'm learning curses in python, and wanted to add an attribute to the curses window object.

my minimal program is:

```
import curses
try:
  stdscr = curses.initscr()
  stdscr.cur_line = 0
finally: 
  #clean-up so your terminal isn't wrecked by above error
  curses.nocbreak()
  stdscr.keypad(False)
  curses.echo()
  curses.endwin()
```

The error is:

```
$ python3 tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp", line 4, in <module>
    stdscr.cur_line = 0
AttributeError: '_curses.curses window' object has no attribute 'cur_line'
```

However, this works:

```
class Temp:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
t = Temp()
t.cur_line = 0 #does not fail
```

My questions is: When does dynamically adding a field to an instance fail? How is python discerning between an instance of my user defined class, and an instance of the class from the curses library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often, this happens because you're trying to add attributes to libraries written in C, and not pure python objects.

```
>>> import pickle, cPickle
>>> pickle.dump.a=1
>>> cPickle.dump.a=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: That's not the whole story. Python objects can prohibit adding attributes, and objects written in C can allow adding objects (though I don't know an example off-hand).

Comment: It'd be cool to see an example or evidence of this, esp. how to go about prohibiting addition to a pure python object.

Comment: @turbulencetoo [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Comment: If you want a bit of LBYL, you can inspect the type's `__dictoffset__`. If it's non-zero, instances have a dict. For example, `type(pickle.dump).__dictoffset__ != 0` and `type(cPickle.dump).__dictoffset__ == 0`.